# React: Passing state from child to child to parent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, jsx

I am trying to pass a value through 2 child elements to the parent. The chain looks like this:

`Child1 > Child2 > Parent`

However, My parent handler is not grabbing the value in `Child1`. I trying to console log the state of `theString` in the parent component, however, nothing displays. How do i pass the handler function to child1 and grab its value to store in state?

**Child 1**

```
  <input ref="theString" type="string" onChange={this.props.handleChangeOfString} value={this.state.theString} />
```

**Child 2** Component

```
<Tab tabId="4">
   {this.props.nav4Content}
   {this.props.handleChangeOfString}
</Tab>
```

**Parent** Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       theString: ''
    };
    this.handleChangeOfString = this.handleChangeOfString.bind(this);
}
```

**Parent** Component:

```
<StringComponent
  nav4Content={colorsTab}
  onChange={this.handleChangeOfString}
/>
```

**Parent** Handler:

```
handleChangeOfString(e) {
  this.setState({theString: e.target.value})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you are passing props from `child2` to `child1`. You are not passing the values as props but as `children` in the `child2` component. Change it to

```
<Tab 
   tabId="4" 
   nav4Content={this.props.nav4Content} 
   handleChangeOfString={this.props.onChange}
/>
```

Comment: This is not calling the handler function successfully. I am trying to log out the change inside the handler but nothing is being passed to it.

Comment: Is your child1 component `Tab`, or how is child1 rendered from child2

Comment: I had to rework my component like you said and update the props!